# How to remove rows with negative days

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data frame that looks like this with multiple rows:

```
id       type       date_1       date_2       time_delta
1         a      2019-01-19     2019-01-10    9 days
1         b      2018-01-10     2019-01-10    -365 days
```

The `time_delta` column is equal to the subtraction of `date_2` from `date_1`, and columns `date_1` and `date_2` are in pandas.datetime format.

I'd like to delete all rows with negative values in the `time_delta` column.

I've tried to cast the row as an integer and then remove the rows like this:

```
df['time_delta'] = int(df['time_delta'])
df = dx_reg.ix[df['time_delta'] < 0]
```

But I get this error:
`df['time_delta'] = int(df['time_delta'])
    df = df.ix[df['time_delta'] < 0]

But I get this error: 
`TypeError: cannot convert the series to class 'int'`

Answer (score 2):

Convert `0` to `timedelta`:

```
df = df[df['time_delta'] > pd.Timedelta(0)]
```

Or convert column to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
df = df[df['time_delta'].dt.days > 0]
```

---

```
print (df)
   id type      date_1      date_2 time_delta
0   1    a  2019-01-19  2019-01-10     9 days
```